# Type guard of function type

Tags: typescript, typeof

I have a function with a union type between `string` and a function type. How can I write a type guard to narrow to that function type? (The following doesn't work.)

```
interface Callback {
    (args: any[]): void
}

var fn = function(arg: string | Callback) {
    if (typeof arg == 'Callback') {
        arg.call([]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `typeof` operator **never** returns `'Callback'`. It always returns one of 'function', 'string', 'number', 'boolean', 'object', or 'undefined'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) won't ever return `'Callback'`. In this scenario it will work to do an `instanceof Function` check:

```
interface Callback {
    (args: any[]): void
}

var fn = function(arg: string | Callback) {
    if (arg instanceof Function) {
        arg.call([]);
    }
};
```

Alternatively this also works:

```
if (typeof arg === "function") {
    arg.call([]);
}
```

Comment: Unlike `typeof arg === 'string'`, using `typeof arg === 'function'` doesn't cause TypeScript to recognize `arg` as a function, and therefore is a compile error on `call`.

Comment: @ZevSpitz That's strange... I'm not having that issue. [See here](http://goo.gl/6LQ4li) how arg is recognized as `Callback`.

Comment: @DavidSherret Oddly enough, if you add an `else { arg += "foo"; }`, it no longer works correctly.